# git fetch giving fatal error from submodules

Tags: git, gitlab

I've been trying to fix an old problem with a `.gitmodules` file containing a submodule with the name `--force` and at some point got the `.gitmodules` file with the problem onto the gitlab repo. I've fixed the issue locally but now can't push to gitlab because fetching from it gives a fatal error about the `.gitmodules` file.

```
$ git fetch -a
fatal: bad config line 1 in file path/to/repo/.gitmodules
```

I've had a look at trying to rebase the gitlab repo to a commit before this issue, but this requires that I can fetch it and I can't do that.

Any help or advice is appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a workaround not a fix. I cloned the repo and copied the `.git` directory into the local repo I was working in and I don't think it's deleted anything. This isn't a fix, but it might work for some similar cases. As ever, backup your repo before trying this